# .net mvc 4 web api service connection to SQL Server issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

**The setup**

We have a .net mvc 4 web api service layer, that is accessed via a web app, which gets data from a SQL Server 2008 database.

**The problem**

When more than 5 GET requests are being made to the web service at the same time, a `500 Interal Server Error` is returned to the web app.  When I look closer at the .net error I see the following:

> An error has occurred.
>   The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

**The C# service code where the exception is being thrown:**

```
public class ImageLinkRepository : IImageLinkRepository
{
  private SqlConnection cnnSQL = new SqlConnection(...);

  public IEnumerable<ImageLink> Get(String userId)
        {

            ImageLinks = new List<ImageLink>();

            // open connection to DB
            cnnSQL.Open();

            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmmSQL = new SqlCommand("nVision_select_lcimagelinks_sp", cnnSQL);
                cmmSQL.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter prmSQL = cmmSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@LCIMGLINKUSERID",
                    Value = userId
                });

                SqlDataReader rdrSQL = cmmSQL.ExecuteReader();

                if (rdrSQL.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rdrSQL.Read())
                    {
                        ImageLinks.Add(new ImageLink 
                        { 
                            // set new ImageLink object's properties    
                            imageTopicId = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKIMGTOPICID"), 
                            id = DBReader.SQLInt(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKPK"),
                            recordId = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKRECORDID"),
                            text = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKTEXT"),
                            topicId = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKTOPICID"),
                            topicItem = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKTOPICITEM"),
                            url = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKURL"),
                            user = DBReader.SQLString(rdrSQL, "LCIMGLINKUSERID")
                        });
                    }
                }    
            }

            // close connection to DB
            cnnSQL.Close();

            return ImageLinks;
        }
}
```

I have tried to manually close the connection if it is open and I have tried to only open the connection if its closed, neither of them work.

I must be doing something wrong, surely, the service should be able to handle simultaneous requests.   What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely exhausting the SQL Connection Pool.  To start with you should be wrapping your `SqlCommand`, `SqlConnection`, and `SqlReaders` with `using()` statements to ensure they are correctly disposed of and closed.

The `SqlConnection` being constructed as a field means that your controller has to be responsible for Disposing of it.  It's easier to construct it within the method, where it can be wrapped in a `using()` as well (otherwise you're class should implement `IDisposable()`, calling `.Dispose()` on the Connection in turn).

```
try
{
  using (var cnnSQL = new SqlConnection(...))
  {
    using (var cmmSQL = new SqlCommand("nVision_select_lcimagelinks_sp", cnnSQL))
    {
      cmmSQL.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      SqlParameter prmSQL = cmmSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
      {
          ParameterName = "@LCIMGLINKUSERID",
          Value = userId
      });

      using (var rdrSQL = cmmSQL.ExecuteReader())
      {
      ...
      }
    }
  {
} ...
```

Comment: Adding the 'using' block fixed the problem.  Since some service classes multiple methods defined, it seemed to make more sense to declare the connection outside of each method and have them share the same `SQLConnection` object. I just didnt know about implementing `IDispoasable()`.  I added the `Dispose()` method call after I closed the connection but it always return the 500 Error back to the web app.  In any event, thanks!

Comment: Read up on .NET's SQL Connection Pooling, under the hood it actually reuses connections--even though it appears to be creating new ones entirely from scratch.